# How to change label from backend in magento 1.9.3?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want to change the label from '**F**' to Fax number in backend in magento.
Kindly suggest me how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the label from 'F' to 'Fax number' from the following backend configuration.

> System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address
>   Templates > HTML

[configuration_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfIqk.png)

We can manage this configuration at store level.